# My LSTM model overfits over validation data

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification, lstm

Here's my LSTM model to classify hand gesture. Initially, I had 1960 training data of shape(num_sequences, num_joints, 3) that  I reshape to shape(num_sequences, num_joints*3).

Here's my model:

```py
input_shape = (trainx.shape[1], trainx.shape[2])
print("Build LSTM RNN model ...")
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(171, 66)))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=256,  activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128,  activation='tanh',    return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128,  activation='tanh',    return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(units=trainy.shape[1], activation="softmax"))

print("Compiling ...")
# Keras optimizer defaults:
# Adam   : lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9,  beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8, decay=0.
# RMSprop: lr=0.001, rho=0.9,                   epsilon=1e-8, decay=0.
# SGD    : lr=0.01,  momentum=0.,                             decay=0.
opt = Adam()
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I get a 90% accuracy on train and 50% on test

Comment: Hi, overfitting is a pretty common problem in deep learning. Could you be reformulate the questions and be more specific on which steps you took to try to solve the problem?

Comment: I modified Dropout value, reduced number pf LSTM cells, changed optimizer, but I have the same problem. I can try data augmentation, but I don't know wether it's gonna be interesting

Comment: Show the ‘model.fit’ part of the code!

Comment: @Bharath batch_size = 128                  
num_epochs = 30                   
history = model.fit(
    trainx,
    trainy,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    validation_data= (testx, testy)
)

Comment: I guess it's the distribution of samples, split them with proper stratification and it might work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Overfitting is quite common in deep learning.
To circumvent over fitting with your LSTM architecture try the following things in this order:

1. Decrease the learning rate from 0.1 or 0.01 to 0.001,0.0001,0.00001.
2. Reduce the number of epochs. You can try to plot the training and validation accuracy as a function of the number of epochs and see when the training accuracy becomes larger than the validation accuracy. That is the number of epochs that you should use. Combine this with the 1st step decreasing the learning rate.
3. Then you can try to modify the architecture of the LSTM, here you already added dropout (maximum value 0.5), I would suggest to try 0.2, 0.3. You have 3 cells which is better than 2, the size of the nodes look reasonable. What is the embedding dimension you are currently using? Since you are overfitting it is worth a try to reduce the number of cells from 3 to 2 and keeping the same number of nodes.
4. The batch size might be important as well as the distribution of subclasses in your dataset. Is the dataset equally distributed and equally balanced between training and validation sets? What I mean by this is that if one hand gesture is over represented in the training set compared to the validation set that might be a problem. A good strategy to overcome this is to keep some part of the data as a test set. Then do a train/split cross validation using sklearn (5 times). Then train your architecture on each train/split model separately (5 times) and compare the training and validation accuracy. If there is a big bias in the split or among the sets you will be able to identify it in this manner.
5. Last, you can try augmentation, specifically rotation and horizontal/vertical flip. This library might help https://github.com/aleju/imgaug

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the network is over fitting versus some kind of error in your data set. Does the validation loss improve initially up to some epoch then plateau or start to increase? Then it is over fitting. If it starts at 50% and stays there it is not an over fitting problem. With the amount of drop out you have over fitting does not look very likely. How did you select your validation set? Was it randomly selected from the overall data set or did you do the selection? It is always better to randomly select the data so that its probability distribution mirrors that of the training data. As said in the comments please show your code for model.fit there could be a problem there. How do you input the data? Did you use generators? A 50% validation accuracy leads me to suspect some error in how your validation data is provided to the network or some  error in labeling of the validation data. I would also recommend you consider the use of dynamically adjusting your learning rate based on monitoring of validation loss. Keras has a callback for this
called ReduceLROnPlateau. Documentation is  [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/). Set it up to monitor validation loss. I set the parameters patience=3 and factor=.5 which seems to work well. You can think  of training as descending into a valley. As you descend the valley gets narrower. If the learning rate is to large and remains fixed you won't be able to reach further down toward the minimum. This should improve your training accuracy which should result in improvement of validation accuracy. As I said with the level of drop out you have I do not think it is over fitting but if it is you can also use Keras regularizes to help avoid over training. Documentation is [here](https://keras.io/regularizers/).